# Displaying a screen shot generated UIImage is not displaying in UIImageView (for device only)

Tags: iphone, uiimage, opengl-es-2.0, glreadpixels, cgimageref

I am trying to save an OpenGL buffer (whats currently displayed in the view) to the device's photo library. The code snippet below works fine on the simulator. But for the actual device it is crashing. I believe there could be a problem with the way im creating the UIImage captured from the screen.

- This operations is initiated via an IBAction event handle method.
- The function i use to save the image is UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum (i recently changed this to ALAssetsLibrary's writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum).
- I have ensured that my app is authorized to access the Photos library.
- I also made sure that my CGImageRed is globally defined (defined at the top of the file) and my UIImage is a (nonatomic, retain) property.

Can somebody help me fix this issue? I'd like to have a valid UIImage reference that was generated from the glReadPixels data.

Below is the relevant code snippet (call to save to photo library):

```
-(void)TakeImageBufferSnapshot:(CGSize)dimensions
{
   NSLog(@"TakeSnapShot 1 : (%f, %f)", dimensions.width, dimensions.height);
   NSInteger size = dimensions.width * dimensions.height * 4;
   GLubyte *buffer = (GLubyte *) malloc(size);
   glReadPixels(0, 0, dimensions.width, dimensions.height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
   GLubyte *buffer2 = (GLubyte *) malloc(size);
   int height = (int)dimensions.height - 1;
   int width = (int)dimensions.width;

   for(int y = 0; y < dimensions.height; y++)
   {
       for(int x = 0; x < dimensions.width * 4; x++)
       {
           buffer2[(height - 1 - y) * width * 4 + x] = buffer[y * 4 * width + x];
       }
   }

   NSLog(@"TakeSnapShot 2");

   // make data provider with data.
   CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer2, size, NULL);

   if (buffer) free(buffer);
   if (buffer2) free(buffer2);

   // prep the ingredients
   int bitsPerComponent = 8;
   int bitsPerPixel = 32;
   int bytesPerRow = 4 * self.view.bounds.size.width;
   CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
   CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
   CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;

   NSLog(@"TakeSnapShot 3");

   // make the cgimage
   g_savePhotoImageRef = CGImageCreate(dimensions.width, dimensions.height, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);

   NSLog(@"TakeSnapShot 4");

   // then make the uiimage from that
   self.savePhotoImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:g_savePhotoImageRef];

   CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
   CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
}

-(void)SaveToPhotoAlbum
{
   ALAuthorizationStatus status = [ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus];
   NSLog(@"Authorization status: %d", status);

   if (status == ALAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
   {
       [self TakeImageBufferSnapshot:self.view.bounds.size];

       // UPDATED - DO NOT proceed to save to album below.
       // Instead, set the created image to a UIImageView IBOutlet.
       // On the simulator this shows the screen/buffer captured image (as expected) -
       // but on the device (ipad) this doesnt show anything and the app crashes.
       self.testImageView.image = self.savePhotoImage;
       return;

       NSLog(@"Saving to photo album...");
       UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.savePhotoImage,
                                   self,
                                       @selector(photoAlbumImageSave:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                   nil);
   }
   else
   {
       UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Access is denied"
                                                    message:@"Allow access to your Photos library to save this image."
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Close"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
       [alert show];
   }
}

- (void)photoAlbumImageSave:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error     contextInfo:(void *)context
{
   self.savePhotoImage = nil;
   CGImageRelease(g_savePhotoImageRef);

   if (error)
   {
       NSLog(@"Error saving photo to albums: %@", error.description);
   }
   else
   {
       NSLog(@"Saved to albums!");
   }
}
```

*** Update ***
I think i've managed to narrow down my issue. I started doing trial & error, where i run the app (on the device) after commenting out lines of code, to narrow things down.  It looks like i may have a problem with the **TakeImageBufferSnapshot** function, which takes the screen buffer (using glReadPixels) and creates an CGImageRef. Now, when i try to create a UIImage out of this (using the [UIImage imageWithCGImage:] method, this seems to be why the app crashes. If I comment this line out it seems like there is no issue (other than the fact that i dont have a UIImage reference).

I basically need a valid UIImage reference so that i can save it to the photo library (which seems to work just fine using test images).

Comment: posting your code might be most helpful rather than the memory warning window.

Comment: Are you doing this on main thread?

Comment: try Global Breakpoint:http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&ved=0CGsQFjAH&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmobile.tutsplus.com%2Ftutorials%2Fiphone%2Fobjc_exception_throw%2F&ei=Na-UUd2qI42_ywG2r4CwDQ&usg=AFQjCNGNy6WuxIVDZ9zt0J7OYN2dG0NAuA&sig2=nSdkwegu8RyiXnqttby3zw&bvm=bv.46471029,d.aWc

Comment: Please Enable Zombie and tell me what is says

Comment: @lducool. I dont do anything explicit with threads. I have an IBAction and i call methods from there. So im guessing everthing is on the main thread. Right?

Comment: Also, enabling Zombie didnt seem to reveal anything new or insightful.

Comment: Have you tried leaving out the `CGImageRelease()` call in your *didFinish* method? (Note: This will obviously lead to a huge leak, so it's not a solution, just a test.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I should point out that `glReadPixels()` may not behave the way you expect. If you try to use it to read from the screen after `-presentRenderbuffer:` has been called, the results are undefined. On iOS 6.0+, this returns a black image, for example. You need to either use `glReadPixels()` right before the content is presented to the screen (my recommendation) or enable retained backing for your OpenGL ES context (which has adverse performance consequences).

Second, there's no need for the two buffers. You can capture directly into one and use that to create your CGImageRef.

To your core issue, the problem is that you are deallocating your raw image byte buffer while your CGImageRef / UIImage is still relying on it. This pulls the rug out from underneath your UIImage and will lead to the image corruption / crashing you are seeing. To account for this, you need to put in place a callback function to be triggered on the deallocation of your CGDataProvider. This is how I do this within my GPUImage framework:

```
rawImagePixels = (GLubyte *)malloc(totalBytesForImage);
glReadPixels(0, 0, (int)currentFBOSize.width, (int)currentFBOSize.height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, rawImagePixels);
dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, rawImagePixels, totalBytesForImage, dataProviderReleaseCallback);
cgImageFromBytes = CGImageCreate((int)currentFBOSize.width, (int)currentFBOSize.height, 8, 32, 4 * (int)currentFBOSize.width, defaultRGBColorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault | kCGImageAlphaLast, dataProvider, NULL, NO, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
CGDataProviderRelease(dataProvider);
```

The callback function takes this form:

```
void dataProviderReleaseCallback (void *info, const void *data, size_t size)
{
    free((void *)data);
}
```

This function will be called only when the UIImage containing your CGImageRef (and by extension the CGDataProvider) is deallocated. Until that point, the buffer containing your image bytes remains.

You can examine how I do this within GPUImage, as a functional example. Take a look at the GPUImageFilter class for how I extract images from an OpenGL ES frame, including a faster method using texture caches instead of `glReadPixels()`.

Comment: How do you know im capturing buffer bytes before or after presentRenderbuffer? Im not calling presentRenderbuffer directly anywhere.

Comment: Also, i dont get what you're doing (other than the dataProviderReleaseCallback). In my code i do not release the UIImage or the CGImageRef until AFTER the save to the library is done (which is never called because the function returns before it attempts to save).

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar - The note about glReadPixels() is a cautionary one, because I've seen a lot of people here get tripped up by it. What I'm saying in the above is that you are freeing `buffer` and `buffer2` in your above code well before your UIImage or CGImageRef is deallocated. `CGDataProviderCreateWithData()` does not copy these bytes internally, so when you free that buffer and try to create a UIImage from a CGImageRef based on it, you will either see garbage results or a crash.

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar - To verify this, you can comment out the `if (buffer2) free(buffer2);` line in your above code. I'm betting your application will no longer crash with the creation of an image. However, it will now have a memory leak, which is what the callback function in my above code takes care of. I ran into this exact same thing, with the same behavior you described, and this is how I solved it.

Comment: Yeah, i was able to get passed the crash. I had updated this question into another one (related to the image i read as being a black image). Just now i resolved it by using GLKView's built-in snapshot function, which currently works in simulator AND device.

Comment: But i do believe you answered the original question about the crash, so you deserve the bounty fair and square.

Answer (score 1):

well - from my experience you cannot just grab the pixels that are in the buffer right now
you need to reestablish the right context, draw and grab THEN before finally releasing the context

=> This is mainly true for the device and ios6 in particular

```
EAGLContext* previousContext = [EAGLContext currentContext];
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext: self.context];

    [self fillBuffer:sender];

    //GRAB the pixels here

    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:previousContext];
```

alternatively (thats how I do it) create a new FrameBuffer, fill THAT and grab pixels from THERE

```
GLuint rttFramebuffer;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &rttFramebuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, rttFramebuffer);

[self fillBuffer:self.displayLink];

size_t size = viewportHeight * viewportWidth * 4;
GLubyte *pixels = malloc(size*sizeof(GLubyte));
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
glReadPixels(0, 0, viewportWidth, viewportHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

// Restore the original framebuffer binding
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
glDeleteFramebuffers(1, &rttFramebuffer);

size_t bitsPerComponent = 8;
size_t bitsPerPixel = 32;
size_t bytesPerRow = viewportWidth * bitsPerPixel / bitsPerComponent;
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast;
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, pixels, size, ImageProviderReleaseData);
CGImageRef cgImage = CGImageCreate(viewportWidth, viewportHeight, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
CGDataProviderRelease(provider);

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage scale:self.contentScaleFactor orientation:UIImageOrientationDownMirrored];
CGImageRelease(cgImage);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
```

Edit: removed call to presentBuffer

Comment: Note that using `glReadPixels()` after `-presentRenderbuffer:`, as you describe in the first code segment above, will fail on iOS 6.0+ and is unsupported on earlier iOS versions.

Comment: Yes it did fail somewhere. I wrote the first inline. The thing is that you have to do what i wrote and not try to read the current buffer context currently 'onsceen'

Comment: One thing i want to reiterate - if i apply the UIImage created by TakeImageBufferSnapshot to the UIImageView i can see the image displayed when running from the simulator. But when i run from my iPad device then the image does NOT get displayed in the image view.